# Rails detect if request was AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my action I wish to only respond with processing if it was called from an AJAX request. How do I check?

I want to do something like this:

```
def action
   @model = Model.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|

      if (wasAJAXRequest()) #How do I do this?

         format.html #action.html.erb

      else

         format.html {redirect_to root_url}
   end
end
```

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You can check for a `header[X-Requested-With]` to see if it is an AJAX request. Here is a good [article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/03/detecting-ajax-events-on-the-server) on how to do it.

Here is an example:

```
if request.xhr?
  # respond to Ajax request
else
  # respond to normal request
end
```

Comment: Warning: this does not work on standard `remote: true` calls in newer Rails versions, as the necessary headers don't get set.

Comment: One way to validate an Ajax request is to see if the page reloads, isn't it?

what another way could be if I set `remote: true` ? I mean if `xhr?` doesn't work

Answer (score 16):

If you're using `:remote => true` in your links or forms, you'd do:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { #Do some stuff }
```

You can also check before the respond_to block by calling `request.xhr?`.

Comment: An ajax request doesn't necessarily have to respond with javascript, `$.ajax({dataType: 'html'})` is ajax that responds with HTML. The right way to do this, is the second one you mentioned `request.xhr?`

Answer (score 8):

#### Update:

As of Rails 6.1.0, `xhr?()` does actually (finally) return a boolean value.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0196551e6039ca864d1eee1e01819fcae12c1dc9#diff-60b77e427ea7ba142faa477fac10b8d0134cede4e35a3b1953c425200fadf1acL267-L269

---

#### Original Answer:

The docs say that request.xhr?

```
Returns true if the “X-Requested-With” header contains “XMLHttpRequest”....
```

But BEWARE that

```
request.xhr?
```

returns numeric or nil values not BOOLEAN values as the docs say, in accordance with =~.

```
irb(main):004:0> /hay/ =~ 'haystack'
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> /stack/ =~ 'haystack'
=> 3
irb(main):005:0> /asfd/ =~ 'haystack'
=> nil
```

It's based on this:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb, line 220
def xml_http_request?
  @env['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] =~ /XMLHttpRequest/
end
```

so

```
env['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] =~ /XMLHttpRequest/  => 0
```

The docs:

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionDispatch/Request/xml_http_request%3F

Comment: what is the difference betwheen truythy and boolean? both are not true / false?

Comment: Truthy meaning that when used in a "boolean" context, you have to treat them not as not booleans, but ones that will be cast to bool. Above env['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] =~ /XMLHttpRequest/ returns 0 not false. And 0 is actually truthy, not falsey in ruby: 0 || 1 => 0 But I'm going to alter my post for clarity.

Comment: But its okey to be truthy, the zero means that the text is found at index 0, so its found (and its and ajax request). If text is not found the result is `nil`, which is false.

Comment: Yes, but the convention is generally for method_name? to return BOOL, so this is a gotcha

Answer (score 2):

I like using `before_action` filters. They are especially nice when you need the same filter/authorization for multiple actions.

```rb
class MyController < AuthController
  before_action :require_xhr_request, only: [:action, :action_2]

  def action
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])
  end

  def action_2
    # load resource(s)
  end

  private

  def require_xhr_request
    redirect_to(root_url) unless request.xhr?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
request.xhr?
```

if this return 0 then it means its an ajax request, else it will return nil.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `:remote => true` in links,form, then your response would come in js form instead of HTML, JSON, etc.

```
def action
   @model = Model.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
           format.js
      if (wasAJAXRequest()) #How do I do this?

         format.html #action.html.erb

      else

         format.html {redirect_to root_url}
      end
   end
end
```

you also need to create, action appropriate js file, in your case action name is action, so file name would be - `action.js.erb`. also shift our action code inside `action.js.erb` file