# JSON to be accessed only by AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, browser

I'm creating a web app in Rails which outputs HTML templates (which are created by the user) as JSON. However, I don't want web browsers or crawlers to be able to view the rendered JSON (like when visiting `http://example.com/content.json`), I only want AJAX requests to be able to parse the content. Is this possible and, if so, how can I do it in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if request.xhr?` in your controller to detect whether a request is AJAX or not.

[Rails detect if request was AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220701/rails-detect-if-request-was-ajax)