# Unable to stop layout from being used in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a Rails view in a Bootstrap modal (which is working) without using the default application layout (layouts/application.html.slim). The latter is not working.

I've set the following code (layout nil) in the controller for the appropriate model:

```
class FoundItemsController < ApplicationController
  layout nil
  before_action :set_found_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

I even tried setting it globally via the application controller but the view is still loading in the modal with my website header, footer, etc.

Is there anything else I should be looking for here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the problem was that I was using this in my controller:

```
layout nil
```

instead of:

```
layout false
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

In action:

```
render :layout => false
```

or

In Controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
    layout false, only: [:show]
....
```

Hope to help you

Answer (score 2):

Something else to consider is *how* you're accessing the modal.

If you're using ajax, you can stop all `layouts` rendering using the [`request.xhr?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220701/rails-detect-if-request-was-ajax) method, like so:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout Proc.new {|controller| controller.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to inherent anything at all from your `ApplicationController`, not exclusively layouts then you can inherit as your `ApplicationController` does from `ActionController::Base`.

```
class FoundItemsController < ActionController::Base
  layout nil
  before_action :set_found_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, helpful to understand that. This did remove the layout, however i'm using the application controller to store the current user and need that.