# jQuery File Upload: RailsCast for nested attributes and rails 4, file doesn't show, unless refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-file-upload

I'm following the [jquery file upload video from RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload) but I can't get the images to show up without refreshing the page.

My photo is being uploaded through this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @upload, html: { multipart: true, id: 'add_new_project_photos' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :project_images, ProjectImage.new, child_index: ProjectImage.new.object_id do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.file_field :photo, multiple: true, name: "project[project_images_attributes][][photo]" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I also created a `create.js.erb` file.

```
<% if @project.project_images.new_record? %>
    alert("Failed to upload painting: <%= j @painting.errors.full_messages.join', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
  $("#added_photos").append("<%= j render(@project) %>");
<% end %>
```

My controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  #... other methods

  def create
    @project = Project.new(trip_params)
    @upload = Project.create(trip_params)

    if request.xhr?
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save

        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

My coffee script file

```
jQuery ->
    $('#add_new_trip_photos').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to respond to js as well. In your create method you are only responding to html and json

```
format.js
```

Should be placed inside your respond_to block

Comment: added that after `format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }`, but didn't work.

Comment: I would look in the developer tools in your browser and make sure you are getting the JS as a response first before you change things. Also, if you put your format.js inside the if save condition, you will not see an error if one arises. I would take it out of your if-else, since you are handling the error in your create.js

Comment: When I tried to upload something, I get a POST method with a 302 status and text/html type and also a GET method with a 200 status and xhr type.

Comment: @hellomello In addition to adding `format.js`, you'll need to add `remote: true` to the form to make this an ajax form.

Comment: @FanJin am I adding it to the simple_form_for or the file_field?

Comment: @hellomello To the `simple_form`. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for for more explanation.

Comment: @hellomello Can you verify whether you have an ajax request in the `create` action within controller? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220701/rails-detect-if-request-was-ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87102/discussion-between-hellomello-and-fan-jin).

Comment: @FanJin I'm not entirely sure if I'm checking it correctly, I added it and tried to do a `redirect_to root_url`, but when I try to drag and drop an image into the field, it just uploads the image, and nothing happens. can you post some code to show me how I should check it? I edited my post to see what I added in the create method.

Comment: @hellomello I was busy, if you're in chat again please reply to me directly