# Rails redirect user back to RESTful partial generated with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm not sure if the title makes sense, but it does have all the components of what is going on... let me explain.

I have a view `/settings` which looks like below:

[image: /settings page]

The code for the view is:

```html
<%= render partial: "pages/navigation" %>

  <div class="row">
      <!-- sidebar -->
      <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
        <h3>Your Devices:</h3>
          <ul class="device_list">
            <% @devices.each do |device| %>
              <li class="device">

                <% if device.last_checkin && device.last_checkin > 30.minutes.ago %>
                  <a class="btn btn-success btn-circle-micro"></a>
                <% else %>
                  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-circle-micro"></a>
                <% end %>

                <%= link_to device.name, edit_scan_option_path(id: device.id), :remote => true %>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- content window -->
      <div class="col-md-10 content">
        <%= render partial: 'view_window' %>
      </div>
  </div>

<%= render partial: "pages/footer" %>
```

Here is the edit method in the `scan_options controller`:

```html
def edit
    @selected = ScanOption.where(device_id: params[:id])
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])

    @device.scan_options.new unless @device.scan_options.present?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**/settings/_view_window.html.erb partial**

```html
<div id="settings_window">
  <%= render partial: "scan_options/device_settings", locals: { device: @device } %>
</div>
```

and then **scan_options/edit.js.erb**

```html
$("#settings_window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'device_settings', locals: { device: @selected } ) %>");
```

Which loads **/scan_options/_device_settings.html.erb** which loads the partial to the right in the screenshot above.  At this point, the url in the browser is still `/settings` however the user is actually on `/settings/11/edit` behind the scene.

The problem is that after the user clicks save they are redirected back to `/settings` which is confusing to them since it will always load the first one again, in this case the partial for the Device on the left (Aurora), whereas they might have been editing the Device (Test JSON6) or something else.

So, how can I redirect the user back to `/settings/11/edit`, even though the url will read `/settings'?

I'm not sure if I've included everything that is needed, so please let me know if I need to add any additional code.

Comment: *"So, how can I redirect the user back to /settings/11/edit, even though the url will read `/settings`?"* You shouldn't. It's up to you to build your app to maintain state in the URL. You shouldn't be juggling some kind of additional context that causes `/settings` to sometimes render different things.

Comment: I was afraid of that... this particular area grew out of control with the dev team.  I get to review/refactor things.  boo.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I'm thinking of is keeping a variable in Session to know which device is selected and select it when you go back to settings.

Not seeing any other way

Comment: That was a thought that occurred to me as well.

Comment: sorry I couldn't come up with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Unless you insist on always staying on `/settings` URL, you should be able to leverage **Javascript [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)**. With `pushState` you can change the URL to `/settings/123/edit` upon successful loading of the edit template by AJAX and then the redirect after Save button press should work correctly because the controller will get the proper HTTP referrer.

For this to work consistently you would also probably have to update the edit template so that it is rendered *including* the left column if accessed by a regular GET request but *without the left column* if accessed by an AJAX request. You can use [`request.xhr?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220761/1544012) for differentiating between regular and AJAX requests in your controllers.