# Rails form_with (remote: true) errors

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I need some help here,

I'm getting a error when I try to update a model using ajax from Rails (form_with / remote: true). I was able to work fine with XHR requests for urls that were resources by Rails (see routes below), but with custom urls I'm getting a error.

#### controller:

```
def criar
  @user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      format.js {
        flash[:success] = "Success!"
        redirect_to root_path
      }
    else
      format.js 
    end
  end
end
```

#### rspec (request):

```
put user_criar_path(user), xhr: true,
 :params => { ... }
```

#### view:

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: user_criar_path(@user), method: :put do |f| %>
```

#### routes:

```
namespace :any do
  namespace :things do
    put '/criar', to: 'user#criar'         # problem with XHR
    put '/atualizar', to: 'user#atualizar' # problem with XHR
  end
end

resources :anything   # this one works fine with XHR
```

As you can see in the test.log, `Processing by UserController#criar as` don't have a specific format (maybe that is the problem?).

#### test.log:

```
Processing by UserController#criar as 
  Parameters: { ... }
```

#### error message:

```
Failure/Error:
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      format.js {
        flash[:success] = "Success!"
        redirect_to root_path
      }
    else
      format.js 
    end

ActionController::UnknownFormat:
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

#### Another request test

```
it "should be redirect to (criar)" do
  put user_criar_path(1), xhr: true
  expect(response).to redirect_to(new_session_path)
  expect(request.flash_hash.alert).to eq "To continue, please, sign in."
end
```

#### Error message

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(new_session_path)
  Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <401: Unauthorized>
  Response body: To continue, please, sign in.
```

Observations:

- I already try to changing the url on routes to: 
  `put '/criar', to: 'user#criar', constraints: -> (req) { req.xhr? }`
- As I said before, I was doing the same thing (tests, controller) to others resources using XHR from `form_with` and they are working fine. This one with a custom url that didn't work.
- Rails 5.2 and Rspec 3.6
- Any question, just ask on comments

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `request.xhr?` before the `respond_to` block, as suggested
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220717/5891503)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found and post the solution!

Answer (score 0):

## Reason of the problem

Well, after some search, I find the answer.

The problem related to `ActionController::UnknownFormat` message was due to the request was not well defined, as we could see on the log that I post:

> Processing by UserController#criar as

It was missing the Type/Format (HTML/JS/...etc) in the end of the sentence.

#### The problem was raised by two factors:

1. Using generated-paths from rails on Rspec and passing a parameter to it:

`user_criar_path(1)` or `put user_criar_path(user), xhr: true, params: {...}`

2. Defining my own route (routes.rb)

`get '/user/new', to: 'user#new'  # defining my own route`

instead of

`resources: user, only: [:new]`   # defined by Rails

***Observation***: for routes defined by Rails (resources), passing parameter to the generated-path don't raise the error `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

## Solution

Removing the parameter from the generated-path (for both, Rspec and Rails):

```
put user_criar_path, params: { "user" => { "id" => 1 } }
```

or

```
put user_criar_path, xhr: true, :params => { ... }
```